# Knight's tour depth-first search infinite loop

Tags: java, stack, depth-first-search, knights-tour

I'm trying to solve the [knight's tour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knights_tour) problem using a depth-first search algorithm. The algorithm seems te be looping whenever it has two choices that both result in a dead end. I understand that this is caused because the algorithm resets the 'wasVisited' boolean to false again whenever a dead end is found but i simply don't know how to fix it.

Here's the code i have so far:

```
  public void dfs() { 
    vertexList[0].wasVisited = true;
    theStack.push(0);
    System.out.println("Visited: 0");

    while (!theStack.isEmpty()) {
        int v = getAdjUnvisitedVertex(theStack.peek());
        if (v == -1) {
            vertexList[lastVisited].wasVisited = false;
            theStack.pop();
            System.out.println("Go back to: " + theStack.peek());
        } else {
            vertexList[v].wasVisited = true;
            lastVisited = v;
            System.out.println("Visited: " + v);
            theStack.push(v);
        }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < nVerts; j++) {
        vertexList[j].wasVisited = false;
    }

}

public int getAdjUnvisitedVertex(int v) {
    for (int j = 0; j < nVerts; j++) {
        if (adjMat[v][j] == 1 && vertexList[j].wasVisited == false) {
            if (j != lastVisited) {
                return j;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Thanks in advance :).

Edit:

Here's the updated code and a bit the output:

```
    public void dfs() {
    vertexList[0].wasVisited = true;
    theStack.push(0);
    System.out.println("Visited: 0");

    while (!theStack.isEmpty()) {
        int v = getAdjUnvisitedVertex(theStack.peek());
        if (v == -1) {
            vertexList[lastVisited].wasVisited = false;
            theStack.pop();
            System.out.println("Go back to: " + theStack.peek());
            int backTo = theStack.peek();
            int newDestination = getNextAdjVertex(backTo, lastVisited);
            lastVisited = newDestination;
            while (newDestination == -1) {
                theStack.pop();
                backTo = theStack.peek();
                System.out.println("Go back to: " + backTo);
                newDestination = getNextAdjVertex(backTo, lastVisited);
                lastVisited = newDestination;
                if (newDestination != -1) {
                    vertexList[newDestination].wasVisited = false;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("New Destination " + newDestination);
            vertexList[newDestination].wasVisited = true;
            lastVisited = newDestination;
            System.out.println("Visited: " + newDestination);
            theStack.push(newDestination);
        } else {
            vertexList[v].wasVisited = true;
            lastVisited = v;
            System.out.println("Visited: " + v);
            theStack.push(v);
        }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < nVerts; j++) {
        vertexList[j].wasVisited = false;
    }

}

public int getNextAdjVertex(int currentVertex, int vertexICameFrom) {
    for (int j = 0; j < nVerts; j++) {
        if (adjMat[currentVertex][j] == 1 && vertexList[j].label != vertexICameFrom && vertexList[j].wasVisited == false) {
            return j;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

public int getAdjUnvisitedVertex(int v) {
    for (int j = 0; j < nVerts; j++) {
        if (adjMat[v][j] == 1 && vertexList[j].wasVisited == false) {
            if (j != lastVisited) {
                return j;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

I'm trying to solve this for a 5x5 board so there are 25 verticles (0 - 24). Here's a bit of the output in which the current problem becomes more clear:

```
Visited: 0
Visited: 7
Visited: 4
Visited: 13
Visited: 2
Visited: 5
Visited: 12
Visited: 1
Visited: 8
Visited: 11
Visited: 18
Visited: 9
Go back to: 18
New Destination 21
Visited: 21
Visited: 10
Visited: 17
Visited: 6
Visited: 3
Visited: 14
Visited: 23
Visited: 16
Go back to: 23
Go back to: 14
Go back to: 3
Go back to: 6
New Destination 15
Visited: 15
Visited: 22
Visited: 19
Go back to: 22
Go back to: 15
Go back to: 6
Go back to: 17
New Destination 20
Visited: 20
Go back to: 17
New Destination 24
Visited: 24
Go back to: 17
New Destination 20
Visited: 20
Go back to: 17
New Destination 24
Visited: 24
```

The looping at the end of the output is, ofcourse, not supposed to happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm gonna explain this by an example:

```
A - B - D
    |
    C
```

When the code gets to node C, it finds no other vertices to go to: `v == -1`. What happens then, it clears C and goes back to B. That's all good. But, at B we only know where we came from (the stack contains `[A,B]`). Now it finds the first unvisited vertex, but that's C again!

What you need to, when you go up from C to B, then find the next vertex to visit. You need to list all adjacent in order.

```
int getNextAdjVertex(int currentVertex,int vertexICameFrom) {
  return the first vertex adjacent to currentVertex, bigger than vertexICameFrom
  or -1 if it does not exist
}

if (v == -1) {
  vertexList[lastVisited].wasVisited = false;
  System.out.println("Go back to: " + theStack.peek());
  //going down in the right direction:

  int backTo = theStack.peek();
  int newDestination = getNextAdjVertex(backTo,lastVisited);

  //now same as the else part, a step downward
  vertexList[newDestination].wasVisited = true;
  lastVisited = newDestination;
  System.out.println("Visited: " + newDestination);
  theStack.push(newDestination);
}
```

There is only one small problem, if `newDestination == -1` you need to go up one more level. You'll have to do that in a loop, going up till there is a unvisited vertex.

---

I think the problem is in getNextAdjVertex.

```
System.out.println("Go back to: " + theStack.peek()+","+lastVisited);
```

will give more useful information in finding the problem. But I think this should work:

```
public int getNextAdjVertex(int currentVertex, int vertexICameFrom) {
    for (int j = vertexICameFrom+1; j < nVerts; j++) {
        if (adjMat[currentVertex][j] == 1 && !vertexList[j].wasVisited) {
            return j;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for explaination, it certainly does give me more insight into the problem but i've not been able to fix the problem yet. I've added my updated code to the original post with some output.

Comment: Thanks, there was indeed a problem with getNextAdjVertex which is now fixed. I now run into the problem that the stack will pop() itself empty in the nested while loop until an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundExceptions appears because of a 'backTo' uses a peek() statement.

Thanks for your help so far, i do understand this a lot better now.